# Installation of asset store in WSO2 GREG 4.6.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I have installed WSO2 GREG 4.6.0 and I would like to use the asset store. I had understand that this feature is included with the default installation (https://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance453/Browsing+Jaggery+Applications) but I followed the steps described in the installation and I don't see the /store application. (I see other jaggery applications: /productaplipublisher or /prodcutapistore)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The context of the 'store' application has been changed to '/productapistore' in Greg 4.6.0
We will update this in product documentation.